# Como mapear entidades com chaves compostas no JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-jpa

Tenho um sistema onde todas as tabelas do banco de dados possuem uma coluna `empresa`, que faz parte da `PRIMARY KEY`.

Na tabela de clientes, tenho uma coluna `id` (autoincremento), que juntamente com a `empresa` formam uma chave composta, mapeada da seguinte forma para a entidade Java:

#### Entidade Cliente

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENTES")
public class ClienteEntity implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ClienteId id;

    //getters e setters e demais campos omitidos

}
```

#### Chave composta do cliente

```
@Embeddable
public class ClienteId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "EMPRESA")
    private String empresa;
    @Column(name = "ID_CLIENTE")
    private String idCliente;

    //getters e setters omitidos
}
```

O problema está no mapeamento da entidade Cliente como chave estrangeira no Pedido.

#### Entidade Pedido com Cliente

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PEDIDOS")
public class PedidoEntity implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PedidoId id;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private Integer status;

    @Column(name = "DATA_ENTREGA")
    private LocalDateTime dataEntrega;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns(value = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CLIENTE", referencedColumnName = "ID_CLIENTE", updatable = false, insertable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPRESA", referencedColumnName = "EMPRESA", updatable = false, insertable = false)})
    private ClienteEntity cliente;

}
```

Do jeito que está, estou conseguindo ler os pedidos e trazer o cliente junto através da chamada ao `pedidoRepository.findAll()`.

Porém, não consigo gravar um novo pedido, passando junto o cliente já existente na entidade pedido e fazendo um simples:

```
pedidoRepository.save(pedido);
```

#### Estrutura da tabela de Pedidos

```
EMPRESA    |  ID_PEDIDO   |    ID_CLIENTE   |   STATUS   |   DATA_ENTREGA
```

**Qual é a maneira correta de fazer o mapeamento do Cliente (uma chave estrangeira composta) na classe Pedido?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu exemplo você anotou o relacionamento da seguinte forma:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns(value = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CLIENTE", referencedColumnName = "ID_CLIENTE", updatable = false, insertable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPRESA", referencedColumnName = "EMPRESA", updatable = false, insertable = false)
})
private ClienteEntity cliente;
```

Note que na anotação `@JoinColumn` você preencheu as propriedades updatable e insertable como `false`.

Nesse caso, ao salvar a entidade Pedido, ele não consegue inserir esses campos na tabela porque você especificou que o gerenciador de entidades não devem escrever neles.

Remova essa definição e deixe da seguinte forma:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns(value = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CLIENTE", referencedColumnName = "ID_CLIENTE"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPRESA", referencedColumnName = "EMPRESA")
})
private ClienteEntity cliente;
```

Comment: Eu não quero inserir nem atualizar um cliente através do pedido. Eu só quer salvar no pedido a referência (relacionamento) ao cliente. Não é isso que aqueles atributos dizem?

Comment: Note que os atributos, por mais que estejam em cima da variável cliente, dizem respeito ao RELACIONAMENTO com o cliente, logo se você anota com updatable false, por exemplo, o JPA vai ignorar essa propriedade na atualização, não preenchendo esse campo no RELACIONAMENTO. Não se trata então de salvar a entidade cliente, mas sim de preencher o relacionamento.